# MS Access textbox on a form is rounding numbers

Tags: database-design, ms-access

On a MS Access form, I have a text box that is being auto-filled with data from the second column of a combobox. The combobox is being populated with the results of a query. The query results are returning the numbers I want (such as 2.6 or 4.56). However, when the text box is filled, the number is rounding up or down.

For example, if 4.56 is supposed to be in the text box, the box states '5.00' instead of 4.56. The textbox is set to 2 Decimal places, but I cannot figure out why the textbox is rounding the numbers when they are not rounded in the query, so I am not sure what I am missing. Does anyone happen to have an idea on what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the source of the problem. The data table that the text box was going to be filling was set as a Long Integer type. Changing that to Double solved the problem.